# jquery animate with image rotate doesn't work after first function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, css-transforms

There is an issue with a function call I have that my step for the transform image rotate isn't working after the first time it's called on an initial function call when my page loads. This function is called every time any value is changed on the graph I built. To paint a picture there are two coins that drop from the top of the screen and then rotate twice before they land on a stack of coins. Instead working like that, the coins only drop/animate from the top of the screen every time the function is called.

```
<div id="secondCoin"><img class="coin" src="./images/one_coin.png" alt="Second Coin Drops" /></div>
<div id="firstCoin"><img class="coin" src="./images/one_coin.png" alt="First Coin Drops" /></div>
<div id="showCoins"><img class="coin-stack" src="./images/fullstack_coins.png" alt="Stack of Coins" /></div>

function coinStack(height){
var coinSound = document.getElementById('coin-sound');
var rotateDeg = 720;
// prevents sound play on multiple clicks
coinSound.pause();
coinSound.currentTime = 0;
// causes coin stack to slide upward
$("#showCoins").css("display", "inline-block");
$("#showCoins").css("top", height + "px");
screenWidth <= 400 ? $("#showCoins").stop().animate({top: '3'},1000) : $("#showCoins").stop().animate({top: '0'},1000);
// first coin drops
$("#firstCoin").css("display", "inline-block");
$("#firstCoin").css("top", "-324px");
$("#firstCoin").clearQueue().delay(1000).animate({top: '10', deg: rotateDeg},{
    duration: 350, 
    step: function(now){
        $("#firstCoin").css({ transform: "rotate(" + now + "deg)" });
    }
});
// second coin drops
$("#secondCoin").css("display", "inline-block");
$("#secondCoin").css("top", "-324px");
$("#secondCoin").clearQueue().delay(1400).animate({top: '0', deg: rotateDeg},{
    duration: 350, 
    step: function(now){
        $("#secondCoin").css({ transform: "rotate(" + now + "deg)" });
    }
});
// coin sound effect
coinSound.volume = 1.0;
coinSound.play();
```

}

I've tried using .stop(), .clearQueue(), setting/removing the transform property differently, and checked various methods on stackoverflow. Nothing seems to be working so I'm hoping another set of eyes will spot my issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you get any errors in console, and can you give us the HTML-code so we can try it out?

Comment: No errors come up on the console, and I'll have the html up in just a moment.

Comment: Everything works fine here... Could you describe the problem a little more? I don't get the part "Instead working like that, the coins only drop/animate from the top of the screen every time the function is called." That's the supposed behaviour...

Comment: So what happens the first time the page loads and calls that function is the coins drop from the top of the screen and rotate twice with no problem. As soon as any value is changed in my graph the coinStack function is called and the coins will drop from the top of the screen, but will not rotate anymore. They only rotate the first time with transform:rotate(720deg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a little bit late, but what you need to do is to add another two rotations to your animation for each iteration. That will solve your problem and you can call the same function over and over again.

```js
var rotateDeg = 720; //Declare this outside the function

$('button').click(function() {
  coinStack(400);
})

function coinStack(height) {

  $("#showCoins").css("display", "inline-block");
  $("#showCoins").css("top", height + "px");
  $("#firstCoin").css("display", "inline-block");
  $("#firstCoin").css("top", "-324px");
  
  $("#firstCoin").clearQueue().delay(1000).animate({
    top: '10',
    deg: rotateDeg
  }, {
    duration: 3500,
    step: function(now) {
      $("div").css({
        transform: "rotate(" + now + "deg)"
      });
    }
  });
  
  rotateDeg += 720; //For every animation you add another 720 degrees
};

$("#secondCoin").css("display", "inline-block");
$("#secondCoin").css("top", "-324px");
$("#secondCoin").clearQueue().delay(1400).animate({top: '0', deg: rotateDeg},{
    duration: 350, 
    step: function(now){
        $("#secondCoin").css({ transform: "rotate(" + now + "deg)" });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="secondCoin"><img class="coin" src="#" alt="Second Coin Drops" /></div>
<div id="firstCoin"><img class="coin" src="#" alt="First Coin Drops" /></div>
<div id="showCoins"><img class="coin-stack" src="#" alt="Stack of Coins" /></div>

<button>Push to rotate</button>
```

Comment: Smart man, Zorken. Still kind of find it unbelievable that increasing the rotation each time the function is called is what "allows" it to rotate. Especially since I've used at least 4 different means of changing/resetting that degree value for the transform attribute, but I'll take it if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Because you are doing two full rotations you could either just add two more (+720 deg) or removing the stile from the element with `$(your element).removeAttr('style')` to reset the now variable in the function.

Comment: That was unfortunately one of the methods I used to try and fix my issue to begin with. I didn't have success with trying to change or even remove the style altogether. I'm just satisfied your idea ended up succeeding where all other attempts had failed me. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're executing your code regardless the state of your page.

Try inserting your code inside this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//your code here
})
```

For more information see:
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: That's not the issue. I have a function that is called in $(document).ready with another that calls it with another that calls it like this. initFutureValue(); --> getFutureValue(); --> coinStack(barHeight);